# NAudio ASIO Playback hangs on some devices

Tags: .net, playback, naudio, asio

I was looking for assistance with a bug that seems to occur on some ASIO devices while playing back audio directly to the ASIO device.  If the WAV audio is not stopped before the end is reached, the application will hang and continuously play rapid-fire blips of the last audio (It sounds like a stutter effect).  At that point, the UI thread will hang and the application will need to be force closed.

This issue can be recreated using the "ASIO Direct Demo" provided from NAudio's github site.  All I do is open a WAV file in the demo and click play.  Once the audio reaches the end, the application hangs.

I've tested this issue and found that it occurs on Behringer X-Air x18 but not M-Audio M-Track MKII.  I was wondering if anyone has found a way to code around this bug?  Thank You.

PS - NAudio is an AMAZING framework and Mark Heath (the author) has great tutorials on pluralsight that are totally worth the subscription fee.

Comment: As a sidenote... my current workaround is to spin off a watcher thread that stops the audio if the current position nears the total position but I was hoping there was a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

Some people have reported issues with auto-stop in ASIO (where you reach the end of your input and it attempts to stop playback from within the ASIO callback). So one simple workaround is to pass a never-ending stream to AsioOut, and detect when it has got past the end of your audio, and then Stop playback from outside.

Comment: Hello Mark, thank you for the quick response and for the great framework.  I did see a similar response on another post but I couldn't find any implementation of a never-ending stream.  Do you have any blog posts or answers that describe how it can be done.  

It is my hope that I can create the stream and pass it to the multiplexingaudioprovider on an existing output channel.

Comment: Several streams in NAudio are never-ending. WaveChannel32 can be configured that way, and I think most of the mixing streams too. It's really easy to write your own IWaveProvider that in its Read method reads from a source, and then just returns silence after the source has ended